# Why does OracleParameter implement ICloneable but doesn't provide Clone()?

Tags: c#, .net, oracleclient

I am using the `OracleClient` library version 1.0.5000.0 and I am confused about the `OracleParameter` class and its implementation of `ICloneable`.

This is the definition of the `OracleParameter` class:

```
public sealed class OracleParameter : MarshalByRefObject, IDbDataParameter, IDataParameter, ICloneable {
    public OracleParameter();
    public OracleParameter(string name, object value);
    public OracleParameter(string name, OracleType oracleType);
    public OracleParameter(string name, OracleType oracleType, int size);
    public OracleParameter(string name, OracleType oracleType, int size, string srcColumn);
    public OracleParameter(string name, OracleType oracleType, int size, ParameterDirection direction, bool isNullable, byte precision, byte scale, string srcColumn, DataRowVersion srcVersion, object value);

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public DbType DbType { get; set; }
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public ParameterDirection Direction { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignOnly(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool IsNullable { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int Offset { get; set; }
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    public OracleType OracleType { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public byte Precision { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public byte Scale { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Size { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string SourceColumn { get; set; }
    public DataRowVersion SourceVersion { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(StringConverter))]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString();
}
```

It implements `System.ICloneable`, but there is no `Clone()` method in there.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Are you sure that's the entire class? Where did you get the code? Reflector? You sure you're seeing it all?

Comment: visual studio 2008 F12 - so from metadata. Hmmm...reflector does show object ICloneable.Clone() which is interesting...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET you can explicitly implement interface members by using the following syntax:

object System.IClonable.Clone()
{
}

As a result you can only use the method by explicitly casting to the expected interface.

Also see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.system.icloneable.clone(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to see that.  So it doesn't appear in metadata?  That's a dirty trick.  You just have to "know" this stuff is there.

Comment: Sometimes this can be a good solution to have some required interfaces implemented but don't pollute intellisense.
E.g. implementing Dispose() for the c# "using" syntax but give another "better" method for explicit calling e.g. "Close".

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the answer but I don't know if I've ever seen such horrid API design. If you cache and try to reuse derived parameters it throws an error unless you clone them, but the method to clone is hidden unless you disassemble the class or just "know" it.

I mean Oracle has never been a shining example of API design but this is downright malicious.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up from time to time. :)  Check out the following ...

```
void Main()
{
    var e = new Example();
    I   i = e as I;

    e.m1();  // prints Class m1()
    i.m1();  // prints Interface m1()
}

public interface I
{
  void m1();
}

public class Example : I
{
  public void m1()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Class m1()" );
  }

  void I.m1()
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Interface m1()" );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I get it now, but why in the world would that not show up in metadata?  That's just mean.

Comment: it could be an Ellison conspiracy. :) I'm actually kind of shocked that it does not.  But, I am sure Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) will see it.

Comment: Yeah, Reflector picked it up, but that is an insane bit of API.  If you want to do anything useful with that class it seems like you HAVE to clone it, but that operation is nicely hidden from anyone that doesn't want to disassemble the code.